# "Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "wordpress" not found" I am getting this error although I've deployed it?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I'm trying to deploy the pod that I've already created as a service but I keep getting the aforementioned error.

The first error is because I had already deployed the pods the other day. But the second error is the main problem.

[image]

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Your kubectl run command creates pod and your are trying to expose the deployment. Pod and deployment are different entitites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kubectl run ...
```

is used to create and run a particular image in a pod. <sup>*[[reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run)]*</sup>

```
kubectl expose ...
```

is used to expose a resource (pod, service, replicationcontroller, deployment, replicaset) as a new k8s service. <sup>*[[reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose)]*</sup>

What you are doing is create a *pod* with `kubectl run` and expose a *deployment* with `kubectl expose deployment`. Those are two different resources. That's why you are getting **NotFound** error - because specified *deployment* does not exist.

What you can do is either

```
kubectl expose pod ...
```

or [create a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment).